# The meaning of this code about converting in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

i had a function containing code like this:

```
Random x = new Random();
int key = x.Next(0x21, 0x7B);
string nxt = Convert.ToString(key.ToString("X")) + 
Convert.ToString(key.ToString("X"))
 + Convert.ToString(key.ToString("X"))
 + Convert.ToString(key.ToString("X"));
```

Im very new to C#, help me, thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines pick a random integer between 33 and 122 [inclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) (the `0x`s in `.Next()` mean those numbers are expressed in [hexadecimal notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)).

The `key.ToString("X")` part takes that random integer, [converts it to hexadecimal notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), and returns it as a string.

As Blindy pointed out, the `Convert.ToString()` is redundant and not necessary since it is converting a string to a string.

The final "nxt" variable would consist of that new hexadecimal number (as a string) repeated four times.

Here's a couple of other ways to get that string repeated four times:

```
string nxt = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, key.ToString("X"), 4).ToString();

string nxt = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(key, 4));

string nxt = $"{key}{key}{key}{key}";
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is choosing a random number between `0x21` and `0x7B`, converting it to a string in hex and repeating it four times in `nxt`.

There are better ways to create a string with a single character multiple times (for example, the string constructor that accepts a character and a count), and the `Convert.ToString` call is useless since `int.ToString` already returns a string.